можно ли выполнить .reg файл через python?
есть рег файл:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000005
"EnableInstallerDetection"=dword:00000001
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000001
"EnableSecureUIAPaths"=dword:00000001
"EnableVirtualization"=dword:00000001
"FilterAdministratorToken"=dword:00000000
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:00000001

как его установить через сам python чтобы все значения корректно встали?

короче пришлось через subprocess это делать. кому надо:
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['reg', 'import', 'test.reg'])

Это вообще говоря плохая идея искать какие-то методы чисто python без необходимости. Они все не очень стабильные и иногда ломают систему. Так что через subprocess как раз таки и надо

Можно через ctypes

В python есть библиотека для прямого изменения реестра windows:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html
